# Temporary file handle storage in HTML5

Tags: html, sqlite

Is it possible to obtain file handles in HTML5 and store it as a blob in webDB for upload later?

(Upload selected images when the 3G network is available again, without re-selecting the files.)

The HTML5 will be loaded from the local client device and

```
    action="http://.../insert.jsp"
```

be used to upload the files to the server.

Any help or ideas will be very useful.

C-:

Comment: http://www.google.com/search?q=html5+file+api

Answer (score 0):

Any *File* object can be converted to an URL.

It is simple to do by using object URLs as described by:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications

(I still have to confirm that the URLs remain valid across sessions.)

And it does not remain valid across sessions in Chrome!